# XCode Project files red after renaming project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, project

I have recently renamed my XCode project. In doing so, all my project files became red. Stupidly, I have re imported the project files and deleted the red files. Now, my XCode project will not run. Within 'products' the Appacus.app is still red and cannot be deleted.

How do I go about fixing a problem like this?

Appreciate any help,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Sure you are using versioning, right? Just go back in your git history.

```
git checkout <previous commit>
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "git log" to check the previous version number. Follow by "git checkout " to revert back to last commit.

I am using this script to rename my iOS project. https://github.com/ytbryan/rename

After you rename it, remember to update your Xcode scheme too.